# Почему не пересоздаётся Socket

Tags: java, android, сокет, tcp

Почему не пересоздаётся сокет при том что я его заранее полностью освобождаю, если он естественно создан?

```
        if(socket!= null){
            socket.close();
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket=null;

        }

        socket = new Socket(ip, port);

        output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Log.i("Клиент запущен","Ok");
```

---

**UPD** :

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            LOGGER.info("Socket is open");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Socket not opened", e);
        }
```

А по сути, поставьте бряки и смотрите уже по факту что происходит

Comment: Ну вот короче сделал как вы сказали, исключение стало вылезать, но почему-то оно какое-то не информативное, тему обновил.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас же `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, что говорит о том, что Вы работаете с сетью в главном потоке (чего делать нельзя).

Для устранения данной ошибки Вы можете вынести действия по работе с сетью в вспомогательный поток (например, с помощью `AsyncTask`).